# Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am currently working on an android app, but whenever I try to load certain jar files I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/annotation/WorkerThread.class

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "company.example.com.mobileapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
//compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
//compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding this line

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

So remove the redundancy lines

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

**OR**

> Remove this line
>
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
//compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
//compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: the second option fixed everything

Comment: Thanks, this is really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project.

`Build -> Clean Project`

Run again after cleaning.