# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

I went through several answers available here but nothing worked for me.
1. [Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091366/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

2. [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765538/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug)

project/build.gradle:
https://github.com/abhinituk/Chat/blob/master/build.gradle

app/build.gradle
https://github.com/abhinituk/Chat/blob/master/app/build.gradle

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the full log error

Comment: @Soham I have added the log error.Please have a look now.

Comment: Can you post your App level build.gradle file